# vim indentation switches for long comment blocks

Tags: vim, indentation

Having nothing in my `vimrc` but

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

I get some strange indentation behavior I can't sort out. When typing a long block comment such as

```
/**
  *
  *
  *
  */
```

The `*` comment is automatically added every time I write a new line as expected. However, after 72 lines of this the indentation decides to change:

```
[a bunch of other comment lines above this]
 * Line 70
 * Line 71
* Line 72
* Line 73
```

Suddenly the indentation switches for no reason! I noticed this when I tried formatting a block of comments by visual selection and then hitting `=`, which completely messed it all up. I don't understand why this happens after a prescribed number of comment lines.

Can someone explain this? I thought it must be something in my `vimrc`, but after switching everything off I think it's just part of how vim indents things. I tried using `filetype plugin on` instead, which seemed to work as I typed the comment, but selecting and then indenting through `=` gave the same result.

Comment: That's a very strange error, but I can reproduce it on my end with vim 8. Interesting.

Comment: Exactly which version of vim are you using?

Comment: I am using vim 7.4

Comment: 72 is a commonly-used value for `'textwidth'`, though I don’t see why `'textwidth'` would cause this behavior. Is your `'textwidth'` set to 72, and if so does the indenting behavior change if you use a different value? Do you have any other settings in your `vimrc` that mention “72”?

Comment: Thanks for the idea @RoryO'Kane
I tried changing the textwidth, but it had no effect. I've got everything in my vimrc disabled except "filetype plugin indent on"

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this bug in vim 7.4.2143, I can't explain it, but if you use:

```
filetype plugin on
```

instead of:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

it does not stop indenting at line 72. I hope this knowledge helps you.

Comment: Thanks Henrique. Like I said, I already tried using "filetype plugin on". The indentation still gets messed up when you auto indent.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read better. Have you tried using gq with the code selected in visual mode? (select the block with V and press gq).

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the effect was the same unfortunately.

Comment: Strange. For me, with a .vimrc with only `filetype plugin on`, in vim 7.4.2143, if I have 一 line `/* some text` and a second line `* so much text that will break in more than 72 lines` the gq works correctly.